# Difference between 'Internal Debt' and 'Market Loans' in RBI public debt statistics

Tags: government-debt, central-banking, debt, government, treasuries

While perusing [RBI public debt statistics](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FS_PDS.aspx), I am at my wits end in trying to figure out the table headers.

I am unable to sum up any combination of them to get any other.

Specifically, what is the difference between 'Internal Debt' and 'Market Loans'?

[image]

Comment: where did you see 'Market loans'?

Comment: @Dayne Forgive me, added a screenshot. The issue is that the data loads in the same web address, so I didn't know that the link wouldn't be a direct one to the data.

Comment: See this: https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/PublicationsView.aspx?id=19844. It appears that Market loan (so are next two columns) is a part of internet debt. The link also mentions the original source of data. There you will certainly get more clarity.

Comment: @Dayne Grateful for that link . However, somehow I am not able to add any combination of the other columns to get the 'Internal Debt'. My main intention was to know the amount of borrowing from the Central Bank (which is cosmetic in some ways because it can be wiped off later).

Comment: Yeah I also saw that. Perhaps only important elements of the internal debt are covered here. I think the original source would have a lot of details. For a rigorous understanding you may like IMF's guide on official statistics.

Comment: @Dayne Sure, thank you for your help and effort 